# WPF - PopUp not closed on clicking outside

Tags: wpf, popup, focus

I have Custom control which uses control template as shown in below code block. I need to show popup when user left clicks on the control. Once he/she clicks outside the pop up, it should close.
With `MouseLeftButtonUp`, the pop up is displayed however stays open on clicking outside the popup.
Please note I have set focus on on popup listbox element as soon as pop opens using `behaviours:Focus`

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ControlWithPopup" TargetType="local:CustomizedControl">
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                            <ei:ChangePropertyAction
                                PropertyName="IsDropDownOpen"
                                TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                Value="True" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <Grid>
                        <Popup
                            x:Name="Popup1"
                            Width="100"
                            MinWidth="80"
                            MaxHeight="300"
                            AllowsTransparency="true"
                            IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            Placement="Center"
                            PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                            PopupAnimation="Fade"
                            StaysOpen="False">
                            <Border
                                Background="{DynamicResource SomeBackgroundBrush}"
                                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource SomeBorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource SomeFontBrush}">
                                <ListBox
                                    x:Name="List1"
                                    ItemTemplate="{TemplateBinding DropDownTemplate}"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                    Style="{DynamicResource ListBoxNormalStyle}"
                                    VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
                                </ListBox>
                            </Border>
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsOpen, ElementName=Popup1}" Value="True">
                                    <behaviours:ScrollIntoCenterView TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=List1}" />
                                    <behaviours:Focus TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=List1}" />
                                </ei:DataTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </Popup>
                        <Border
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                            <TextBlock
                                x:Name="Presenter"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                FontSize="11"
                                FontWeight="ExtraBold"
                                Text="{Binding SelectedValue}" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

**Note -**
- Also note, i dont want to set `StayOpen` to True due to some reason outside the scope of the problem. I want to achieve it using `StayOpen` set to False

Comment: Have you considered using a contextmenu rather than popup? Because clicking anywhere outside of a contextmenu will close it.

Comment: I don't want to use Context menu since this control is present in common library and could affect many projects using it. I am just trying to extend its functionality.